# R - Concatenate string from dataframe and remove html tags

Tags: html, r, concatenation

I'm looking to use R to clean up some text strings from a database.  The database stores the text complete with HTML tags.  Unfortunately, due to database limitations, each string is broken into multiple fragments in the database.  I think I could figure out how to remove the html tags with regular expressions and the help of other posts, but I don't expect those solutions will work unless I concatenate the fragments back together (opening/closing html tags can be spread across records in the dataframe).  Here is some sample data:

**Existing dataframe**

```
Record_nbr  fragment    Comments
1   1   "The quick brown"
1   2   "fox jumped over"
1   3   "the lazy dog."
2   1   "New Record."
```

**Desired output dataframe**

```
Record_nbr  fragment    Comments
1   3   "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
2   2   "New Record."
```

**Data:**

```
dat <- read.table(text='Record_nbr  fragment    Comments
1   1   "The quick brown"
1   2   "fox jumped over"
1   3   "the lazy dog."
2   1   "New Record."', header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `fragment` column becomes unusable after the split?  Maybe

```
> aggregate(dat[3], dat[1], paste)
#   Record_nbr                                             x
# 1          1 The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
# 2          2                                   New Record.
```

equivalent to

```
aggregate(Comments~Record_nbr, data = dat, paste)
```

Comment: `grouped <- aggregate(dataframe[[12]], dataframe[1:9],paste, collapse = " ")`

Comment: like `aggregate(dat[-1], dat[1], paste)` for this example

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you didn't actually want to keep the fragment column. In this case you can use this quick one-liner:

```
aggregate(comment ~ Record_nbr, data=dat, function(x) paste(x, collapse=" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of many approaches:

```
## ensure order
dat <- with(dat, dat[order(Record_nbr, fragment), ])

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$Record_nbr), function(x) {
    data.frame(
        x[1, 1, drop=FALSE], 
        fragment = max(x[, 2]), 
        Comments = paste(x$Comments, collapse=" ")
    )
}))

##   Record_nbr fragment                                      Comments
## 1          1        3 The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
## 2          2        1                                   New Record.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
group_by(Record_nbr) %>% 
summarize(fragment= n(), Comments=paste(Comments, collapse= " "))

#  Record_nbr fragment                                      Comments
#1          1        3 The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
#2          2        1                                   New Record.
```

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using the quicker 'aggregate' function:

```
aggregate(dat,  by=list(dat$Record_nbr), paste, collapse=" ")

##   Group.1 Record_nbr fragment                                      Comments
## 1       1      1 1 1    1 2 3 The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
## 2       2          2        1                                   New Record.
```

Edit: You might have to play with the function inputs to get the exact outcome you want.